# How to right shift each row of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, pytorch, autograd

I have a matrix whose shape is (`TxK`, and `K << T`). I want to extend it into shape `TxT`, and right shift the `i`-th row with `i` steps.

For an example:

```
inputs: T= 5, and K = 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3

expected outputs:
1 2 3 0 0
0 1 2 3 0
0 0 1 2 3
0 0 0 1 2
0 0 0 0 1
```

My solutions:

```py
right_pad = T - K + 1
output = F.pad(input, (0, right_pad), 'constant', value=0)
output = output.view(-1)[:-T].view(T, T)
```

My solution will cause the error -- `gradient computation has been modified by an in-place operation`. Is there an efficient and feasible way to achieve my purpose?

Comment: Your expected output does not have the right size in your example. It's a 5x6 matrix now.

Comment: sorry about that, I have fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is fine and is not a cause of your error (using `PyTorch 1.6.0`, if you are using other version, please update your dependencies).

Code below works fine:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

T = 5
K = 3

inputs = torch.tensor(
    [[1, 2, 3,], [1, 2, 3,], [1, 2, 3,], [1, 2, 3,], [1, 2, 3,],],
    requires_grad=True,
    dtype=torch.float,
)

right_pad = T - K + 1
output = F.pad(inputs, (0, right_pad), "constant", value=0)
output = output.flatten()[:-T].reshape(T, T)

output.sum().backward()

print(inputs.grad)
```

Please notice I have explicitly specified `dtype` as `torch.float` as you can't `backprop` integers.

`view` and `slice` **will never** break backpropagation, as the `gradient` is connected to single value, no matter whether it is viewed as `1D` or unsqueezed `2D` or whatever. Those are not modified in-place. In-place modification breaking gradient could be:

```
output[0, 3] = 15.
```

Also, your solution returns this:

```
tensor([[1., 2., 3., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 2.],
        [3., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], grad_fn=<ViewBackward>)
```

so you have a `3` in the bottom left corner. If that's not what you expect, you should add this line (multiplication by upper triangular matrix with `1`) after `output = output.flatten()[:-T].reshape(T,T)`:

```
output *= torch.triu(torch.ones_like(output))
```

which gives:

```
tensor([[1., 2., 3., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 2.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], grad_fn=<AsStridedBackward>)
```

And `inputs.grad`:

```
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this column by column with PyTorch.

```py
# input is a T * K tensor
input = torch.ones((T, K))

index = torch.tensor(np.linspace(0, T - 1, num=T, dtype=np.int64))
output = torch.zeros((T, T))
output[index, index] = input[:, 0]
for k in range(1, K):
    output[index[:-k], index[:-k] + k] = input[:-k, k]
print(output)
```

Comment: I am not sure that the copy operation between the `input` and `output` will retain the gradient backpropagation.

Comment: @Beanocean, There shouldn't be a problem for backpropagation when assigning the values to the output tensor. Does your training fail when using this piece of code ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I double-checked my code, and I found that the error is caused by another bug.